# How do I Copy Results With Headers from a 'View' in SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio

Tags: view, sql-server-2008-r2, copy, resultset, export-to-csv

I'm having difficulties determining how to copy/export the headers for a 'View' I created.

With my tables if I right click on the query results, I see an option to `Copy with Headers` as in this picture:

[image: Copying from Table]

But when I try the same for results from a custom view, I don't see the option to `Copy with Headers`:

[image: Copying from View]

Is this possibly a setting or is it even possible? If there were an export results to a file option also that would be awesome.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Rob.

Disclaimer:  I'm a total beginner with SQL Server Management Studio.  I pretty much just have to do this one database migration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply copy and paste the SQL code from the view into a new query window and the 'Copy with Headers' option will be available. This seems to be a limitation of the results panel when in 'Design' mode

Comment: Thank you for response, I was in 'Design' mode.  When I created a new Query with the SQL it worked perfectly.  Exactly what I was looking for...Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you look on the `Query` menu, under `Results To`, you will see the different output options, which includes directly outputting to a file.

[image: Results to File]

Comment: Thank you for the response.  As I mentioned in the other comments to the other person that answered the question, I was in 'Design' mode.  When I was in design mode I couldn't see the Query menu. Showing the top 1000 rows or copy/pasting the SQL to a new query worked.  Thanks again for your response.  Cheers, Rob.